# Does March 2015 CU include all previous security patches?

Tags: update

How can I be sure that March 2015 CU includes all security patches that are important for me:
[MS13-100](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/ms13-100),
[ms13-067](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/ms13-067),
[ms14-022](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/ms14-022),
[MS14-050](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/MS14-050),
[MS14-044](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/MS14-044),
[ms15-036](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/ms15-036.aspx),
[MS15-047](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/MS15-047)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their are 2 security bulletin which released after the March CU 2015( MS15-036 & MS15-047), so those are not part of the March CU. You can install them separately or Install the latest CU i.e May 2015 which include all the previous since the baseline.

Check the response from MSFT folk on [this blog( last comment so far).](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2015/05/12/sharepoint-security-fixes-released-with-may-2015-pu-and-offered-through-microsoft-update.aspx)

In order to check if a CU contains old files, You Can extract it and if the msp file for the same components are included the it contains the prev fixes.

Comment: How can I extract a CU?

Comment: you can right click and extract it using zip software.